# Notice: Use of undefined constant Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN - assumed 'Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN'

Tags: plugins, themes, constants, textdomain

I am building my first Wordpress site, I just downloaded and installed v3.9.1. I bought a theme (rustik3) and I am trying to install it, but I am running into these errors produced by WP_DEBUG:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN - assumed 'Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN' in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/options.php on line 501

Notice: Use of undefined constant Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN - assumed 'Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN' in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/options.php on line 502

Notice: Use of undefined constant Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN - assumed 'Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN' in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/options.php on line 503

Notice: Undefined variable: item_info in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/theme-functions.php on line 23
```

I have done some googling, and I'm starting to think that the last Wordpress update made it so that the Redux Framework is deprecated and cannot be used. This is just a hunch though. As of right now, the theme installs, but it shows up as completely blank - either when I go to `http://localhost` or when I am trying to customize it in the Wordpress UI. I haven't looked into the last part of the error messages log (line 23 error)...but it is just an undefined variable so I might be able to tackle that one myself. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

This is what the chunk of code looks like in `options.php`:

```
array(
            'id' => 'google_webfonts',
            'type' => 'google_webfonts',
            'title' => __('Enable Google Webfonts', Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN), 
            'sub_desc' => __('Pick from over 600 Google Webfonts to use on the site. Then select below which elements you want to apply it to.', Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN),
                'desc' => __('', Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN)
      ),
```

**UPDATE**

I did a text search through all of the wordpress files for `Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN` and the only spot it appears is in the above chunk of code...

**UPDATE**

This code is what loads the text domain in the theme I have...I am not familiar with what a text domain is - but this might be relevant:

```
public function load_textdomain() {
        if ( isset( $this->textdomain_loaded ) )
            return $this->textdomain_loaded;

        $textdomain = $this->get('TextDomain');
        if ( ! $textdomain ) {
            $this->textdomain_loaded = false;
            return false;
        }

        if ( is_textdomain_loaded( $textdomain ) ) {
            $this->textdomain_loaded = true;
            return true;
        }

        $path = $this->get_stylesheet_directory();
        if ( $domainpath = $this->get('DomainPath') )
            $path .= $domainpath;
        else
            $path .= '/languages';

        $this->textdomain_loaded = load_theme_textdomain( $textdomain, $path );
        return $this->textdomain_loaded;
    }
```

Is there something wrong with the above code?

Note: I have posted a duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492618/wordpress-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-redux-text-domain-assumed-redux). I did this before I was aware that there was a Wordpress specific section of Stack Exchange. If you care about stackoverflow.com - you can answer the question there...I have put a 50 point bounty on it :). You should also read the comments on that page...I think I may have found some relevant information.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to a comment by cybmeta - I got rid of the `Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN` errors...the last one left is this:

`Notice: Undefined variable: item_info in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/theme-functions.php on line 23`

Here is the code:

```
$item_info .= '<div class="rustik_updated"><div class="mc_embed_signup_admin">
        <form action="http://doublerainbowx.us6.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post?u=eac2b83a92633c39dae8a663b&amp;id=334c60b856" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
            <label for="mce-EMAIL">Get e-mails about important updates and helpful tips on how to run your store by joining the Rustik newsletter.</label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
            <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_eac2b83a92633c39dae8a663b_334c60b856" value=""></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
            <span><a href="?rustik_updates_nag_ignore=0">Hide Notice</a></span>
        </form>

        </div></div>';

        echo $item_info;
```

The error is thrown on the `echo $item_info` line - so it is as if it isn't being set for some reason...even though it looks like it is above.

Comment: if `Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN` it is not a PHP constant, you should write it as string (between quotes) to pass it as the textdomain parameter of a gettext function.

Comment: @cybmeta I think it is a constant though - part of the theme...some part of it is dependant on this aspect of the Redux Framework...I think

Comment: @cybmeta I tried it and it got rid of the error! the only one i have left is this one now...`Notice: Undefined variable: item_info in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/theme-functions.php on line 23` any ideas?

Comment: @cybmeta im updating my question to show the code in theme-functions.php

Comment: @cybmeta is `$item_info` not being set because of `.=` what is the difference between that and just using `=`?

Comment: @cybmeta - you can submit your comment as an answer and I will accept it (that was mainly what i was wondering about with this question) but if you could help with the last error that would be awesome!

Comment: @cybmeta crazy idea...but what if i changed the outer `'` to `"` and then made all the inner quotes `'`? I am thinking that `'` might not be working because it is supposed to be a string...is this right?

Comment: @cybmetan - my quote idea didn't help lol

Comment: Well, `Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN` was not a constant, that is what the error said, remember? "Use of undefined constant `Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN`". Your new problem is again a basic and pure PHP question: With `.=` your are trying to concatenate a value with the previous value of `$item_info`, but `$item_info` has not been defined previously so it is an "Undefined variable:". I'm soory to be rude but your question is not related with Wordpress itself but with PHP coding basic knowledge. I think you should ask in another SE site, for example [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @cybmeta - thanks for your help! your not being rude lol! just correct haha. i might be able to tackle this myself...starting to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `$item_info` is that the variable is not initialized before your try to append to it. `$item_info .= 'String content';` is the exact same thing as `$item_info = $item_info . 'String content';`, so all you need is to check whether or not this variable exists:

```
if (!isset($item_info)) { 
    $item_info = '';
}
$item_info .= '<div class="rustik_updated"><div class="mc_embed_signup_admin">
    <form action="http://doublerainbowx.us6.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post?u=eac2b83a92633c39dae8a663b&amp;id=334c60b856" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Get e-mails about important updates and helpful tips on how to run your store by joining the Rustik newsletter.</label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
        <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_eac2b83a92633c39dae8a663b_334c60b856" value=""></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
        <span><a href="?rustik_updates_nag_ignore=0">Hide Notice</a></span>
    </form>

    </div></div>';
```

Sometimes developers sell themes/plugins without testing them with warnings ON, that's why you have this error.

Comment: oooo thanks...the `if (!isset($item_info)) { 
    $item_info = '';
}` looks promising...wouldn't have thought to do that...I am not on the computer with my stuff on it...so ill check it out when i can and get back to you...thanks!

Comment: incase it doesn't work lol - `$item_info` is declared and set with `=` in another file (so im not just trying to set it with a string concatination - i think you realize this already judging by your idea for a solution...but what reasons would it have to not recognize `$item_info` if it is being declared in a different file?

Comment: if file is not loaded, if var failed to be initialized, you always have to verify that thing exist even if you just declared it.

Comment: good to know - haven't gotten around to trying yet...so this is like a php best practice type thing? or you are saying it will never work unless i do what you suggested?

Comment: it's more a best practice.

Comment: it's a pleasure.